# Faulty Edimax Bluetooth on Ubuntu 22.04.3

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth, wireless-keyboards, dongle

I've tried 2 Bluetooth dongles, however no successful connection via Ubuntu, however works on Mac Mini:

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)

Bus 003 Device 003: ID 7392:c611 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd Edimax Bluetooth Adapter
```

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep Bluetooth
[sudo] password for ubuntu:          
[    1.768778] usb 3-4: Product: Edimax Bluetooth Adapter
[    4.596895] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.596926] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.596931] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.596933] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.596938] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    6.809196] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    6.809204] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    6.809209] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   10.403526] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   10.403565] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   10.403585] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 2563:0523 ShenZhen ShanWan Technology Co., Ltd. BM0523 WirelessGamepad
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1ea7:0064 SHARKOON Technologies GmbH 2.4GHz Wireless rechargeable vertical mouse [More&Better]
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 1c4f:0002 SiGma Micro Keyboard TRACER Gamma Ivory
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The Bluetooth keyboard Logitech K760 works with the Mac Mini.